# Doctrine triple quotes sql alias

Tags: sql, database, symfony-1.4, dql, doctrine-1.2

I have following sql error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.`role`' in 'field list'
```

My doctrine select is

```
$query->select('a.role AS role');
```

When i look on the symfony error i see that doctrine makes the 'a.role' to `a`.`role`.

Here the full SQL Statement =

````
at Doctrine_Connection->execute('SELECT `a`.```role``` AS `a__0`, `a`.`role` AS `a__0` FROM `offer` `o` INNER JOIN `account` `a` *******)
````

Comment: Can you paste the whole query builder statement?

Comment: Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Offer base')->innerJoin('base.Account a')->leftJoin('base.AddressEvent ae')->where('1')

Comment: Hm. This is quite strange. Although I know that when you limit the select part of the query Doctrine expects you to select at least one field from the base table. So try to use `$query->select('base.id, a.role')`. Also do you really need the `role as role`? It will be named `role` anyway. Doctrine uses its' own internal aliases when creating SQL but will use the original column names when it hydrates the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best practice to not even use backticks.  The only time they are necessary is when you are using tables that are reserved words, and it is suggested you don't do that in the first place.

Turn off quoting by using the `quote_identifier` attribute in your databases.yml.  An example of the output is referenced [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/configuration.html#identifier-quoting).

Example databases.yml:

```
default:
  class:          sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql:dbname=database_name;host=localhost
      username: username
      password: password
    attributes:
      quote_identifier: false
      use_native_enum: false
      validate: all
      default_table_charset: utf8
      default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
```